# Use multiple inputs to filter divs based on keywords with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I am trying to create a filter for service plans where the inputs in a form append data to a hidden field's value, and then a filter uses that value to match keywords in a hidden div in the individual plan. It's a mouthful, but it seems like it should be basic.

I have plans that have a list of keywords that are hidden from display, but have words like "1user" or "2user" or "gaming" or "streaming" etc. A user would select an amount of users from a dropdown, an amount of devices from a dropdown, and a series of checkboxes with other features. This would end up making the hidden input look like this:

```HTML
<input id="filter" class="filter-checkbox" 
     type="hidden" value="1user streaming">
```

OR

```HTML
<input id="filter" class="filter-checkbox" 
     type="hidden" value="2user 2device gaming">
```

There's really a bunch of combinations. Then the filter should look through a series of products, which contain a div with a class of "hidden-features" and see if any of those words match any of the words in the div.

```HTML
<div data-box-number="1" class="singleplan plan1">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Plan 1</p>
    <div class="hidden-features" style="display:none;">
       1user streaming
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-box-number="2" class="singleplan plan2">
  <div class="content">
  <p>Plan 2</p>
  <div class="hidden-features" style="display:none;">
    1user 2user 1device gaming</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically if you chose 1user in the dropdown, both singleplan divs would show, if you chose 2user in the dropdown, only the second would show. If you chose streaming and 2user, they'd both show because they both have those keywords.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lg0p61q/13/) and my only partially working javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Live Search
    var userSelect       = document.getElementById('userSelect');
    var deviceSelect     = document.getElementById('deviceSelect');
    var filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox');
    var filterInput      = document.getElementById('filter');

    // Event listener for any change in inputs
    userSelect  .addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
    deviceSelect.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
    filterCheckboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
    });

    function updateFilter() {
    
        // User and device values
        var userValue   = userSelect.value;
        var deviceValue = deviceSelect.value;

        // Combine checkbox values
        var checkboxValues = Array.from(filterCheckboxes)
            .filter(function (checkbox) {
                return checkbox.checked;
            })
            .map(function (checkbox) {
                return checkbox.value;
            })
            .join(' ');

        // Combine userValue, deviceValue, checkbox values, and update the filter input
        var filterValue = userValue + ' ' 
                        + deviceValue + ' ' 
                        + checkboxValues.toLowerCase();
             // Convert to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison

        // Update the hidden #filter input
        filterInput.value = filterValue;
       
        // Loop through the singleplan elements
        document.querySelectorAll('.singleplan').forEach(function (singleplan) {
            var hiddenFeaturesDiv = singleplan.querySelector('.hidden-features');
            var hiddenFeaturesText = hiddenFeaturesDiv.textContent.toLowerCase();

            // Split the comma-separated text into an array of words
            var hiddenFeaturesWords = hiddenFeaturesText.split(',').map(function (word) {
                return word.trim();
            });

            // Check if userValue is present in hiddenFeaturesWords
            var containsUserValue = hiddenFeaturesWords.includes(userValue.toLowerCase());

            // Check if deviceValue is present in hiddenFeaturesWords
            var containsDeviceValue = hiddenFeaturesWords.includes(deviceValue.toLowerCase());

            // Check if any checkbox value is present in hiddenFeaturesWords
            var containsCheckboxValue = Array.from(filterCheckboxes).some(function (checkbox) {
                var checkboxValue = checkbox.value.toLowerCase();
                return hiddenFeaturesWords.includes(checkboxValue);
            });

            // Check if filterValue is empty or contains only spaces
            var isEmptyFilter = filterValue.trim() === '';

            // If checkbox value is present or filterValue is empty, show the list item; otherwise, hide it
            if (containsUserValue 
              || containsDeviceValue 
              || containsCheckboxValue 
              || isEmptyFilter
              ) {
                singleplan.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                singleplan.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });

    }

    
});
```

Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems which I found in your code.

**First:**

```
var hiddenFeaturesWords = hiddenFeaturesText.split(',').map(function (word) {
   return word.trim();
});
```

You are separating hiddenFeatures by comma expecting to get array of filter keywords which you use in the next lines to fliter users, devices, etc. But the actual text is not comma separated but space separated. So this should be :

```
var hiddenFeaturesWords = hiddenFeaturesText.split(' ').map(function (word) {
    return word.trim();
});
```

**Second:**

```
var containsCheckboxValue = Array.from(filterCheckboxes).some(function (checkbox) {
    var checkboxValue = checkbox.value.toLowerCase();
    return hiddenFeaturesWords.includes(checkboxValue);
});
```

Rather than the checkboxes selected by the user, you are iterating over all the checkboxes and checking if the hiddenFeaturesWords includes any of them which is always true since every hiddenFeaturesWords includes at least one checkbox. So you should be iterating only the selected checkboxes. It should be like this:

```
var containsCheckboxValue = Array.from(checkboxValues.split(' ')).some(function (checkbox) {
    var checkboxValue = checkbox.toLowerCase();
    return hiddenFeaturesWords.includes(checkboxValue);
});
```

**Here is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/PY15208/wjurLy8f/4/)**